# Aggregation by count and dummified column in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following toy dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                   'text':['Oh no Monday','Oh no Monday','Gotcha !',
                           'Coffee, please','Coffee, please','Mails ',
                           'Oh no Monday','Oh no Monday'],
                   'dates':['2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000','2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000',
                           '2019-05-25T19:40:43+0000','2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000',
                           '2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000','2019-04-10T19:50:49+0000',
                           '2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000','2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000'],
                   'personne':['Simon','Tintin','Milou','Asterix','Asterix',
                               'Iznogoud','Iznogoud','Iznogoud'],
                   'theme':['light','light','funny','dark','sad','funny','light','funny']})
df.sort_values(by = 'text')

    id  text            dates                       personne    theme
3   4   Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000    Asterix     dark
4   5   Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000    Asterix     sad
2   3   Gotcha !        2019-05-25T19:40:43+0000    Milou       funny
5   6   Mails         2019-04-10T19:50:49+0000    Iznogoud    funny
0   1   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    Simon       light
1   2   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    Tintin      light
6   7   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    Iznogoud    light
7   8   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    Iznogoud    funny
```

and I want to aggregate by `text` and `dates` creating new columns, one for the most common `personne` and the other one to the dummified `theme`.This is the expected result:

```
    id  text            dates                       personne    theme_dark  theme_sad   theme_funny  theme_light    
3   4   Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000    Asterix     1           1          0            0          
2   3   Gotcha !        2019-05-25T19:40:43+0000    Milou       0           0          1            0
5   6   Mails         2019-04-10T19:50:49+0000    Iznogoud    0           0          1            0
7   8   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    Iznogoud    0           0          1            1
```

I have tried this, I'm almost at it but I can't select the most frequent of the column `personne`

```
pd.concat([
    pd.get_dummies(df.drop('id', 1), columns=['theme'])
      .groupby(['text', 'dates']).max(), 
    df.groupby(['text', 'dates'])['id'].first()
], 1).reset_index()


    text            dates                       personne    theme_dark  theme_funny  theme_light  theme_sad   id
0   Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000    Asterix     1           0            0             1          4
1   Gotcha !        2019-05-25T19:40:43+0000    Milou       0           1            0             0          3
2   Mails         2019-04-10T19:50:49+0000    Iznogoud    0           1            0             0          6
3   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    Tintin      0           1            1             0          1
```

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `agg` before `get_dummies`

```
out = df.groupby(['text', 'dates']).agg({'id':'first','personne':lambda x :x.mode().iloc[0],'theme':lambda x : ','.join(set(x))})
out = out.join(out.pop('theme').str.get_dummies(',').add_prefix('theme_')).reset_index()
out
Out[286]: 
             text                     dates  ...  theme_light theme_sad
0  Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000  ...            0         1
1      Gotcha !  2019-05-25T19:40:43+0000  ...            0         0
2         Mails   2019-04-10T19:50:49+0000  ...            0         0
3    Oh no Monday  2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000  ...            1         0
[4 rows x 8 columns]
```

More detail

```
out.pop('theme').str.get_dummies(',').add_prefix('theme_').values
Out[283]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Hello @BENY, for the row `Oh no Monday` the most frequent `personne` is `Iznogoud`, not `Tintin`. I have tested your code and the result for that row is `Tintin`

Comment: I have tested again and for some reason, it returns me `Tintin`, but it should return `Iznogoud`. Is it possible that the `max` argument returns the max value alphabetically?? Quite strange

Comment: The lambda function worked great! Thank you very much @BENY